# Xamarin: How do I override a label style class for all labels?

Tags: xml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In a nuget package there is an Xaml file with:

```
<Style x:Key="LabelBase" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Green" />
</Style>

<Style
    BasedOn="{StaticResource LabelBase}"
    Class="Primary"
    TargetType="Label">
</Style>
```

In the current project App.xaml I have:

```
<Style TargetType="Label">
   <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Red" />
</Style>
```

The ResourceDictionary has `MergedWith="XAMLFILE"`, the nuget .xaml file ResourceDictionary.

In the AbsoluteLayout of a page I have a label

```
<Label
    Grid.Row="0"
    FontSize="45"
    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
    StyleClass="Primary"
    Text="Text Value"
    VerticalOptions="Center" />
```

How do I override the Primary StyleClass in my projects App.Xaml to get the text color to inherit red without creating a new styleclass?

Answer (score 2):

If you want that Theme to be applied to all the labels just remove the class and it should work :

```
<Style
BasedOn="{StaticResource LabelBase}"
TargetType="Label">
</Style>
```

See to it you do not have a key and that the style is in APP.xaml

Good luck

Feel free to revert.

Comment: I am not able to remove the class nor change the App.xaml file from the nuget package. I want to know if there is a way to override that class in the current projects App.xaml file.

Comment: Which NuGet package is this? It's unusual to have App.xaml in a NuGet.

Comment: What NuGet package are you talking about?

Comment: It's an in house nuget package.

Comment: Then just merge that resource dictionary into this project and then use it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries